# Generating function for seven constrained die rolls

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is it possible to get a generating function when you throw 7 distinct dice that gives a sum of r if the first 3 dice are odd and the last 3 are even .  no mention of the 4th (middle die which can be either odd or even )

my answer is

$(x+x^3+x^5)^3\times(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)\times(x^2+x^4+x^6)^3$

the middle term being the 4<sup>th</sup> die.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can't get a sum from the generating function, as the sum can change with each trial (and the generating function only produces one number associated with the sum, namely the coefficient of $x^{n}$). You could get the probabilities. The coefficient $[x^{n}]$ tells you the number of ways in which the sum is equal to $n$. This divided by $3^{3}\cdot 3^{3} \cdot 5^{1}=405$, the total number of outcomes, gives you the probability of getting this sum. Hence dividing your polynomial by $405$ gives you the generating function for the probability of your sum being equal to $n$.